# Was there any effort within the Regional Comprehensive Economic Partnership to add a provision for protecting smallholder farmers?

Tags: international, trade

> The deal, which will progressively lower tariffs across many areas,
> could become the world's biggest trade agreement, with the 15 nations
> making up nearly a third of the global population and about 30% of its
> gross domestic product.
>
> It aims to counter protectionism, boost investment and allow freer
> movement of goods within the region. **But the deal lacks provisions for
> protecting workers and the environment, and will hurt smallholder
> farmers and businesses** at a time when they are already suffering from
> the pandemic, said Arieska Kurniawaty at Solidaritas Perempuan in
> Indonesia.

https://www.reuters.com/article/us-asean-rights-agreement-trfn/fears-worlds-biggest-trade-deal-could-spark-conflicts-hurt-farmers-idUSKBN27T15K/

Was there any effort within the Regional Comprehensive Economic Partnership to add a provision for protecting smallholder farmers? As of now, I didn't find any provision within the RCEP that would protect smallholder farmers, but I was wondering if any member country made any effort to add a provision to achieve that.